# Xcode framework headers in red

Tags: xcode, frameworks, header

I add my own framework, when I link against it it an app and run the app everything goes smooth. But I can't seem to access the framework headers from within my app. The framerwork's header file shows me my headers in red (like when you clean you project and your product file turns red). Any ideas? they are set as public headers, and I use them in the app already.

Comment: When you say "I can't seem to access the framework headers from within my app," what do you mean? Are you simply trying to look at them in Xcode while editing the text of your source files? Or are you trying to open them from within your application?